# how to synchronize data between two connects

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I'm using a python tool called "Ajaxterm"(http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Ajaxterm). After setting it up. The problem  , I face is,when type few chars - they appear as jumbled character.For example,When i type "abcde" it may come as "cdbea" - but no character missing.   From my understanding - I tried to debug the python code,it seems like ajaxterm internal server (qweb - QWebRequest Request Handler) processes the request it.There seems to be nothing wrong with it.

The problem is (I assume) - From .js file (javascript) to ajaxterm.py , for every character i type a connect() is initiated and thus  characters typed later may be arriving sooner than the previously typed character.

How should I make sure,character appear in the order it was typed.

(The problem is does (mostly) happen only when network is slow)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have been checking 'ajaxterm.js' I just instaled and there is code to properly queue the requests. Are you using a recent version? Just installed it from synaptic and got version 0.10-10ubuntu2.

Comment: Yes,I'm using 0.10.10 on fedora machine i got the src from http://git.kirya.net/?p=debian/ajaxterm.git;a=shortlog (sometimes it doesn't happen - but most times it happens)

Comment: I don't know, we have made some changes like adding " <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2-min.js"></script>"  instead of the one used by ajaxterm by default. Is there any other like strace .py file will help to find out whats going wrong where & why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Prusse,It works now - I have increased time limit from 1 to 200 on function queue(s)